# HTTP post Json 400 Error

Tags: python, json, http-post

I am trying to post data to my server from my microcontroller. I need to send raw http data from my controller and this is what I am sending below:

```
POST /postpage HTTP/1.1
Host: https://example.com
Accept: */*
Content-Length: 18
Content-Type: application/json

{"cage":"abcdefg"}
```

My server requires JSON encoding and not form encoded request.

For the above request sent, I get an 400 error from the server, HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request

However, when I try to reach the post to my server via a python script via my laptop, I am able to get a proper response.

```
import requests
url='https://example.com'
mycode = 'abcdefg'



def enter():
    value = requests.post('url/postpage', 
                             params={'cage': mycode})
    print vars(value)


enter()
```

Can anyone please let me know where I could be going wrong in the raw http data I'm sending above ?

Answer (score -1):

HTTP specifies the separator between headers as a single newline, and requires a double newline before the content:

```
POST /postpage HTTP/1.1
Host: https://example.com
Accept: */*
Content-Length: 18
Content-Type: application/json

{"cage":"abcdefg"}
```

---

If you don’t think you’ve got all of the request right, try seeing what was sent by Python:

```
response = ...
request = response.request # request is a PreparedRequest.
headers = request.headers
url = request.url
```

Read the [docs for `PreparedRequest`](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/api/?highlight=logging#requests.PreparedRequest) for more information.

---

To pass a parameter, use this Python:

```
REQUEST = 'POST /postpage%s HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: example.com\r\nContent-Length: 0\r\nConnection: keep-alive\r\nAccept-Encoding: gzip, deflate\r\nAccept: */*\r\nUser-Agent: python-requests/2.4.3 CPython/2.7.9 Linux/4.4.11-v7+\r\n\r\n';
query = ''
for k, v in params.items():
    query += '&' + k + '=' + v # URL-encode here if you want.
if len(query): query = '?' + query[1:]
return REQUEST % query
```

Comment: I followed the same syntax as you have posted. Just dint get the formatting right in my post. Corrected it in the post.

Comment: @J F That doesnt work either. Is it somehow possible to see what http raw data the python script is actually sending so that I can replicate that raw data on my micro-controller ?

Comment: @J F I actually managed to get what python is sending (got a success reply from server). It is POST /postpage?cage=abcdefg HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: https://example.com\r\nContent-Length: 0\r\nConnection: keep-alive\r\nAccept-Encoding: gzip, deflate\r\nAccept: */*\r\nUser-Agent: python-requests/2.4.3 CPython/2.7.9 Linux/4.4.11-v7+\r\n\r\n' . cage:abcdefg is being appended to the Post URL instead of being sent as data. How do I modify my http raw data stream posted in the original post to append cage:abcdefg in post ?